# Change default branch name on Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

Every time I go to do a release I branch my code, and in doing so, it suggests a branch name for me which is just my original branch name with -branch appended to the end.  This is annoying, as I put this branch in a separate folder, and have to delete the "-branch" part every time.  Is there a way to configure TFS to not do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read most of the TFS books and ALM rangers guide, and I have never seen this mentioned as a feature, so I am willing to bet **no** - unless there's an unsupported hack out there, but I would be surprised.

Most people won't have a problem with this because they name their branch after the release. It means 1 less level of nesting, which in TFS 2010 can be a problem with long path names in source control.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info. Guess I'll just have to suck it up. :)